# Migration for model inherited from Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

We're using `CustomFlatPage` model derived from `django.FlatPage` model in our application. It works fine, but the `FlatPage` changed in Django 1.9, which triggers the migration for our `CustomFlatPage`. But we'd like to have a clean migrations, that is state where `makemigrations` doesn't create any migrations in 1.8, nor 1.9.

Is it possible to write a migration which would be compatible with Django 1.8 and 1.9 without any change to the `CustomFlatPage` model itself?

Comment: If the model changed in `1.9`, my guess is that the model changes won't work without the proper migrations. If you want to keep the old `CustomFlatPage` model, you can copy it from the `1.8` sources and make it your own. It will permit you to update while keeping this part unchanged.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this, you want your code running both on 1.8 and 1.9?

Comment: @Jerzyk: Yes, exactly.

Comment: so I do not see a solution, because if you create a migration that (depending on django version) will apply changes or not, then there will be issue later on, after user will migrate to 1.9 - then will be missing this migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my investigation and on comments provided, it looks like there is no solution for the moment.